# Recursively create directory

Tags: java, scala, file, recursion

Does anyone know how to use Java to create sub-directories based on the alphabets (a-z) that is n levels deep?

```
 /a
    /a
        /a
        /b
        /c
        ..
    /b
        /a
        /b
        ..
    ..
        /a
        /b
        /c
        ..

/b
    /a
        /a
        /b
        ..
    /b
        /a
        /b
        ..
    ..
        /a
        /b
        ..
..
    /a
        /a
        /b
        ..
    /b
        /a
        /b
        ..
    ..
        /a
        /b
        ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  File root = new File("C:\\SO");
  List<String> alphabet = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    alphabet.add(String.valueOf((char)('a' + i)));
  }

  final int depth = 3;
  mkDirs(root, alphabet, depth);
}

public static void mkDirs(File root, List<String> dirs, int depth) {
  if (depth == 0) return;
  for (String s : dirs) {
    File subdir = new File(root, s);
    subdir.mkdir();
    mkDirs(subdir, dirs, depth - 1);
  }
}
```

`mkDirs` recusively creates a `depth`-level directory tree based on a given list of `String`s, which, in the case of `main`, consists of a list of characters in the English alphabet.

Answer (score 155):

You can simply use the [mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()) method of `java.io.File` class.

Example:

```
new File("C:\\Directory1\\Directory2").mkdirs();
```

Comment: Or `Files.createDirectories` since Java 7

Comment: this should be used as the right answer.

Answer (score 13):

Since Java 7, java.nio is preferred

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

...

Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("a/b/c"));
```

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind relying on a 3rd party API, the [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io) package does this directly for you. Take a look at [FileUtils.ForceMkdir](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#forceMkdir(java.io.File)).

The Apache license is commercial software development friendly, i.e. it doesn't require you to distribute your source code the way the GPL does. (Which may be a good or a bad thing, depending on your point of view).

Comment: By far the best answer for practical purposes (i.e. unless it's an educational exercise).  And forces the "build" issue: even the simplest app requires a build framework, to avoid having to manage command line classpaths, location of jars, etc.  Every programmer should learn Gradle early on: basic use is not difficult.  And then always bung in (and familiarise yourself with) Apache Commons... never reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @ mike rodent Wrong, never reinventing the wheel is a blind cargo-cult fallacy. This is precisely what led to the NPM left-pad debacle. The native IO java library takes care of a lot of this, and the small amount of code needed to reach the end goal is trivial. https://www.davidhaney.io/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `mkdirs()` (as suggested by @Zhile Zou) and your `File` object is a file and not a directory, you can do the following:

```
// Create the directory structure
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

// Create the file
file.createNewFile();
```

If you simply do `file.mkdirs()` it will create a folder with the name of the file.

Answer (score -1):

I would write a little utility method that takes the start and the end letter as well as the desired deepth as parameters. This method calls itself recursively till done:

```
 private static void createAlphabetFolders(File parent, int start, int end, int deepth){

    if(deepth <= 0){
      return;
    }

    for (int i=start; i < end; i++){

      // create the folder
      String folderName = "" + ((char) i);
      File folder = new File(parent, folderName);
      System.out.println("creating: " + folder.getPath());
      folder.mkdirs();

      // call recursively
      createAlphabetFolders(folder, start, end, deepth-1);
    }
  }
```

One would call it like this:

```
createAlphabetFolders(new File("abctest"), 'A', 'E', 5);
```

Answer (score -1):

Scala code:

```
  def makePathRecursive(path: String) = {
    import java.io.File
    import scala.util.{Try, Failure, Success}

    val pathObj = new File(path)
    pathObj.exists match {
      case true => // do nothing
      case false => Try(pathObj.mkdirs) match {
        case Success(_) => // it worked 
        case Failure(e) => // maybe created meanwhile by another thread
          pathObj.exists match { 
          case false => throw new Exception(e)
          case _ =>  
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use three loops over characters `a-z` like so:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileCreate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        char trunkDirectory = 'a';
        char branchDirectory = 'a';
        char leaf = 'a';

        while (trunkDirectory != '{') {
            while (branchDirectory != '{') {
                while (leaf != '{') {
                    System.out.println(trunkDirectory + "/" + branchDirectory + "/" + leaf++);
                }
                leaf = 'a';
                branchDirectory++;
            }
            branchDirectory = 'a';
            trunkDirectory++;
        }

    }
}
```

This simply outputs the paths to the console. You could use [`File#mkdirs()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) to create a recursive directory structure or create the directories in each intermediate part of the nested loop. I'll leave that for you to finish.

Comment: Genius!  Another qn: what if I want to limit to a certain set of alphabets instead?

Comment: If the subset is consecutive then the begin and end characters can easily be changed. If it's a sparse set of characters then it's probably best to create a character array e.g. `char[] alphabet = {'a','e','i','o','u'};` and loop that instead with an index like `for(int i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++) { alphabet[i++]; };`

Comment: And another unexplained downvote 2 years after the last!

Comment: And another unexplained downvote. You people are the best!

Answer (score -2):

```
    // ensures parent directory is created
    File parentFile = destFile.getParentFile();
    if (parentFile != null && !parentFile.exists()) {
        parentFile.mkdirs();
    }

    // creates destination file
    if (!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Apache commons addresses most of these. Try -

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceMkdir(directory);

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question at hand. _How_ does this single method do what is requested? The question is about an algorithm, not about what API to use.

Comment: @jdv how did you determined that this question is about algorithm and not an API, I don't see any such description in the question itself.

Comment: "... how to ..." but my comment is really about a single ref to some external API does not make for a good SO answer.

Comment: I had answered this 6 years before this one. At least read the previous answers before needlessly repeating them.