# Java mkdir -p equivalent

Tags: java, mkdir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recursively create directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774369/recursively-create-directory)

What's the java-esque way to create a director(ies), and don't complain if it exist?

Quoting the man for `mkdir`:

```
-p    Create intermediate directories as required... with this option 
      specified, no error will be reported if a directory given as an 
      operand already exists.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried to read the documentation for [java.io.File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())? The `File#mkdirs()` does just what you need.

Comment: File,mkdirs() suppresses most exceptions and only returns false if something went wrong, so you don't know what's going on. One of the things that could go wrong is that the leaf directory already exists — which is silently accepted by mkdir -p.

Comment: I would appreciate the answer more if it were not condescending.

Answer (score 9):

In Java, both, files and directories are represented as File objects.

So you can do:

```
File file = new File("C:/a");
file.mkdirs();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Using mkdir() only creates the last directory in the path, you need to use mkdirs() to create the entire path.

Comment: Thanks @GaryF, that was a typo. Thank you for not down voting.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for File.mkdirs().

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.